# How to convert from List of Dict into Dict?

Tags: python, json, pandas

**Input Data**:

```
val1 = '[{"EmpID":123456,"AnalystID": "8aa18b9c59XXXXXb20cc2534","173f48XXXXXX427f3f14516dd0"]}]'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
val_op = {"EmpID":123456,"AnalystID": "8aa18b9c59XXXXXb20cc2534","173f48XXXXXX427f3f14516dd0"]}
```

`type(val1)` is `str`
`type(val_op)` is `dict`
(basically I just need to remove first and last single quote which define `Val1` as String).

Approach i tried:

```py
>>> strlen = len(val1)
>>> payloadStr = val1[1:(strlen-1)]

'{"EmpID":123456,"AnalystID": 
"8aa18b9c59XXXXXb20cc2534","173f48XXXXXX427f3f14516dd0"]}'

>>> import json
>>>json.loads(payloadsStr)

{'EmpID':123456,'AnalystID': 
'8aa18b9c59XXXXXb20cc2534','173f48XXXXXX427f3f14516dd0']}
```

Comment: `val_op = dict(*eval(val1))` ...?

Comment: Thanks for response but this will convert double quote into single quote. {'EmpID':123456,'AnalystID': 
'8aa18b9c59XXXXXb20cc2534','173f48XXXXXX427f3f14516dd0']}

I need output like "EMPId"

Comment: Your `val_op` needs some fixing. It is not a well-formed Python dict.

Comment: python dicts have single-quoted keys, you could use `json.dumps(val_op)` ... with this just returnings a formatted str, not a `dict`

Comment: Actually this is required json input format for one of our Post Request api.

Comment: What is wrong with `json.loads`?

Comment: If I use dict with single quote then my api response result in error with text:

"message": "Could not read document: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@c0df5f; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@c0df5f; line: 1, column: 3]",

Comment: I think your solution is fine, it is whoever sent that string who misformatted their json

Comment: 1st: your input AND output have wrong python structures (you're missing a bracket in your output ). 2nd: you could just use `eval(val1)` to get a python variable (if val1 is correctly formatted. 3rd: double and single quote on python are the same thing. When is it that you need double quote? Do you export it somehow?

Comment: your string is missing proper brackets

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to treat the `[]` separately, `json.loads` can handle json list objects.

```
import json
payload = json.loads(val1)[0]
```

Also note that the list value in your string is missing an opening bracket and should instead be...

```
val1 = '[{"EmpID":123456,"AnalystID": ["8aa18b9c59XXXXXb20cc2534","173f48XXXXXX427f3f14516dd0"]}]'
#                                     ^
```

Since you mentionned the string comes from a web request, this means whoever made that request misformatted their json.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, this is a string. From the string, you want to extract a dictionary, that is contained in a list.

This makes it more difficult, as opposed to a simple list that contains a dictionary.

One approach you could do is:

```
val1 = val1.str.split('[')[1].str.split(']')[0]
```

This should get rid of the brackets, and return an array of 1 index, which contains your dictionary in a string.

Another way, more straightforward is:

```
val1 = val1.replace('[','').replace(']','')
```

From there

```
import json
json.loads(payloadsStr)
```

Should get you the dictionary.

Comment: Why not just do `lst[0]`?

Comment: Because list[0] on the string will get you the first character of the string, which is the bracket

by removing the brackets first, you can just use json.loads to convert the string into a dict

Comment: @alex067 you should instead treat the string as a json payload (because it is) and load it first, then parse the payload. `json.loads(payload_string)[0]`

Comment: note also that `val1.replace('[', '')` is probably awful, since it will replace _all_ `[` with the empty string. You could use `val1.replace('[', '', 1)`, but then how do you do so from the right? You could instead try `val1.strip('[]')` which will strip all open and close brackets from both ends of the string. That produces other inconsistent behavior if your payload is a list of lists, but works in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for all the solutions. Since Desired output need to have double quote, hence json.loads(val1) and dict(*eval(val1)) can not be used.
I just tried to replace the [] from original string and when passed in Post Request as data payload, it worked fine.

strlen = len(val1)

payloadStr = val1[1:(strlen-1)]

response = requests.request("POST", url, verify=False, data=payloadsStr, headers=header)

response.text

got the output. Apologies for any confusion. Thanks Again